# Wrong Result by $lookup mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am using **$lookup** to get the data by joining data from two or three collections, Below is my aggregate query.

```
let condition = {status:{$ne:config.PROJECT_STATUS.completed}, assignId:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)};

Project.aggregate([
  { 
        "$match": condition 
  },
  { 
        "$group": { "_id": "$_id" }
  },
  { 
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "worksheets",
            "let": { "projectId": "$_id" },
            "pipeline": [
              { 
                "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$projectId", "$$projectId"] } } 
              },
              { 
                "$group": { "_id": "$projectId", "totalHours": { "$sum": "$hours" } }
              },
              { 
                "$lookup": {
                "from": "projects",
                "let": { "projectId": "$_id" },
                "pipeline": [
                  { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$projectId"] } } },
                  { 
                    "$lookup": {
                      "from": "users",
                      "let": { "developers": "$developers" },
                      "pipeline": [
                        { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$_id", "$$developers"] } } },
                        { "$project":{"firstName":1,"lastName":1}}
                      ],
                      "as": "developers"
                    }
                  },
                  { 
                    "$lookup": {
                      "from": "billing_accounts",
                      "let": { "upworkId": "$upworkId" },
                      "pipeline": [
                        { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$upworkId"] } } },
                        {"$project":{"name":1,"username":1}}
                      ],
                      "as": "upworkId"
                    }
                  },
                  { 
                    "$project": { 
                      "projectName": 1, "upworkId": 1, "status": 1, "developers": 1,  "hoursApproved": 1
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "as": "project"
            }}
           ],
            "as": "projects"
          }
    }
])
```

**And it is giving me the below result:**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5c188a9959f6cf1258f4cb01",
        "projects": [
            {
                "_id": "5c188a9959f6cf1258f4cb01",
                "totalHours": 8,
                "project": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5c188a9959f6cf1258f4cb01",
                        "hoursApproved": 192,
                        "developers": [
                            {
                                "_id": "5c0a29e597e71a0d28b910aa",
                                "lastName": "kumar",
                                "firstName": "Amit"
                            }
                        ],
                        "projectName": "Jims fitness",
                        "status": "ongoing",
                        "upworkId": [
                            {
                                "_id": "5c17a1cec1a7681f7c54bb2d",
                                "name": "Heena Ln",
                                "username": "heena_ln"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5c17a253c1a7681f7c54bb2f",
        "projects": []
    }
]
```

**But what i want to get is:**

```
[
        {
            "_id": "5c188a9959f6cf1258f4cb01",
            "projects": [
                {
                    "_id": "5c188a9959f6cf1258f4cb01",
                    "totalHours": 0,
                    "project": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5c188a9959f6cf1258f4cb01",
                            "hoursApproved": 192,
                            "developers": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5c0a29e597e71a0d28b910aa",
                                    "lastName": "kumar",
                                    "firstName": "Amit"
                                }
                            ],
                            "projectName": "Project1",
                            "status": "ongoing",
                            "upworkId": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5c17a1cec1a7681f7c54bb2d",
                                    "name": "Heena Ln",
                                    "username": "heena_ln"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c17a253c1a7681f7c54bb2f",
            "projects": [
             {
                    "_id": "5c17a253c1a7681f7c54bb2f",
                    "totalHours": 0,
                    "project": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5c17a253c1a7681f7c54bb2f",
                            "hoursApproved": 192,
                            "developers": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5c0a29e597e71a0d28b910a9",
                                    "lastName": "kumar",
                                    "firstName": "Rajat"
                                }
                            ],
                            "projectName": "project2",
                            "status": "ongoing",
                            "upworkId": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5c17a1cec1a7681f7c54bb2d",
                                    "name": "Heena Ln",
                                    "username": "heena_ln"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
             ]
        }
 ]
```

As you can see that now i have **totalHours equals to 0** instead of **empty array** and have the **project details**.

Actually I have four collections: **projects**, **worksheets**, **users** and **billings** and i am executing aggregate query on the **projects** collection to get the projects of a project manager and for this i am also joining **worksheets** collection to get the data for how many hours the employees worked on this project, because worksheets collection contains the projectId, userId and hours.

**Query:** You can see in the result that, i am getting the empty array of projects, this is because i don't have any record of second project projectId into the worksheet collection, so for this it is giving me empty array, but i want to get the projects details as it is and totalHours equals to 0.

Comment: Remove the `$group` stage.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyWinzlet, It works. But i want data in manner. It is returning me all the data not specific fields. Can you please help in it?

Comment: Use `$project`. Something like `{ $project: { "fieldYouWant": 1, "fieldYouWant": 1 }}`

Comment: please try to understand, i want to get data in above structure. But when project  not exists in worksheets collection, it just shows 0 in totalHours field.

Comment: Above written query is working very well. But when project not exists in worksheet collection then it is giving empty projects Array. But i want to get the data in projects Array same like other documents have but with totalHours = 0.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, Can you please modify the above query to meet my need?

Comment: Sorry but it is still unclear what you are asking

Comment: okay, no problem. I have fixed the issue. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi @AnthonyWinzlet, I have one question, are you there?

Comment: If the question is related to the above question then you can. Otherwise please ask a new question

Comment: I want to $project condition vise. Like if i have variable data = 'somevalue', then i have to project one more field, how can I?

Comment: use `$cond` aggregation. [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)

Comment: I did, but mongodb giving me syntax error:

Comment: $cond: { if: {(req.query._id)}, then: {$project : { projectName : 1, upworkId : 1, status:1, developers:1, hoursApproved:1, hoursSpent:1, requirements:1 }}, else: {$project : { projectName : 1, upworkId : 1, status:1, developers:1, hoursApproved:1, hoursSpent:1 }} }

Comment: can you correct this?

Comment: should i again need to again ask a new question for this?

Comment: Yes with proper explanation. Always put a sample collection and the output to your question

Comment: okay, i will do.

Comment: stackoverflow is asking to add new question after 90 minutes. Can you please tell me here.

Comment: I modified my query and it is working now. below is my query->

requirements:
           {
             $cond: { if: (req.query._id), then: $requirments, else: false }
           }

Comment: now if i write 1 instead of 1, then it is returning me 1. But i want to get the value of this field in collection. How can i? As you can see, i also used $requirments. But it is still not returning me the value in collection.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, Are you there? I have asked a new question about the update query with conditions and with proper explanation. Can you please help me regarding this?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, Do you know answer of above question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895150/update-multi-documents-condition-vise-in-mongodb?noredirect=1#comment94636355_53895150