# Update multi documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 projects of a **particular user** in `schedule` **collection** and in every record(document), I have field isActive, which `user` will set to true when he wants to work on that project, and can set for only one project.See below records:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c1e0a1cd8a20917b8564e49"),
    "isActive" : true,
    "projectId" : ObjectId("5c0a2a8897e71a0d28b910ac"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c0a29e597e71a0d28b910aa"),
    "hours" : 1,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c1e0a1cd8a20917b8564e4a"),
    "isActive" : false,
    "projectId" : ObjectId("5c188a9959f6cf1258f4cb01"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c0a29e597e71a0d28b910aa"),
    "hours" : 7,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c1e0a1cd8a20917b8564e4b"),
    "isActive" : false,
    "projectId" : ObjectId("5cyt2a7797e71a0d25b930ad"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c0a29e597e71a0d28b910aa"),
    "hours" : 1,
}
```

**for example**, User has completed his work for `5c0a2a8897e71a0d28b910ac` this **projectId**. Now he wants to work for `5c188a9959f6cf1258f4cb01` projectId, So i want to write update query to update isActive to true for `5c188a9959f6cf1258f4cb01` projectId and isActive to false for `5c0a2a8897e71a0d28b910ac` and for `5cyt2a7797e71a0d25b930ad` projects, means user other projects.

Comment: I actually don't get it. what do you mean by `particular projectId` and `user projects`

Comment: Want to update isActive key to true for a specific project for all records of user.

Comment: @test Unclear what you are asking here

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, I have 3 records of a user in schedule collection. Every record containing, on which project and for how many hours, the user has to work. And now completing time on one project, user want to switch on another project. So i am asking, i want to update isActive to true for particular projectId from that records and isActive to false for remaining projects.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, Please ask from me again, if it still unclear to you.

Comment: You have to use two queries here one 1) for particular `projectId` `Model.update({ projectId: projectId }, { $set: { isActive: true }})` and the second one to update `isActive` false for the other `projectId` i.e. `Model.update({ projectId: { $ne: projectId }}, {$set:{ isActive:false }},{multi:true})`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, I explain in details what i want, Please check my updated question.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, I think, Your above answer can solve my problem. Can you please post your answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you have  to use two queries one to `$set` `isActive` to `false` and one to `$set` `isActive` to  `true` for a particular `userId`

1) to set `isActive` to `true`

```
Model.update(
  { "projectId": "5c188a9959f6cf1258f4cb01", "userId": "5c0a29e597e71a0d28b910aa" },
  { "$set": { "isActive": true }}
)
```

2) to `$set` isActive to `false` for other `projectId` for the same `userId`

```
Model.update(
  { "projectId": { "$ne": "5c188a9959f6cf1258f4cb01" }, "userId": "5c0a29e597e71a0d28b910aa" },
  { "$set": { "isActive": false }}
)
```

Comment: should i need to use second update query, after response of first update query?

Comment: Does not matter :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. I will test it and let you know :-)

Comment: Hello @Anthony, Can't i do above with only one update condition, Can we do it with use of $cond with $set?

Comment: Nopes. Most of the people have same question but till then it is not possible with the single query.

Comment: Can i use pipeline without $lookup?

Comment: Can you please answer this question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922374/use-aggregate-with-group-in-mongodb

Comment: sure I look into it