# Use Aggregate with $group in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have data in `worksheets` collection like below:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c21d780f82aa31334ab6506"),
    "isBilling" : true,
    "hours" : 6,
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c1f38a1d7537d1444738493"),
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c21d780f82aa31334ab6507"),
    "isBilling" : true,
    "hours" : 4,
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c1f38a1d7537d1444738493"),
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c21e10fae07cc1204a5b647"),
    "isBilling" : false,
    "hours" : 8,
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c1f388fd7537d1444738492"),
}
```

I have to create a aggregate query to sum the hours, where isBilling equals to true, and where isBilling equals to false.I want the below output:

```
{
 "billingHours":10,
 "fixContract":8
}
```

**I have to get data with the particular userId. I tried the below:**

```
Worksheet.aggregate([
  {
        $match: conditions
  },
  {
      $lookup:{
          "from": "worksheets",
          "let": {},
          "pipeline": [
            { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$isBilling",false] } } },
            { 
              "$group": { "_id": null, "totalHours": { "$sum": "$hours" } }
            },
          ],
          "as": "billingHours"
      }
  },
  {
        "$project":{"billingHours":1}
  }
])
```

I am getting the below result:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5c21d780f82aa31334ab6506",
        "billingHours": [
            {
                "_id": null,
                "totalHours": 16
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5c21d780f82aa31334ab6507",
        "billingHours": [
            {
                "_id": null,
                "totalHours": 16
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I don't know why it is giving me 16 hours instead of 10 and giving me two objects instead of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) here. Simple [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) will do the job.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "billingHours": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$isBilling", true] }, "$hours", 0]
      }
    },
    "fixContract": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$isBilling", true] }, 0, "$hours"]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: can't i use $lookup on same collection?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: can't i used above query written by me?

Comment: The query you have written doesn't make sense. Why do you make a `$lookup` with the same collection?

Comment: Yes, I also thinked for that. But i didn't have the another option. But you solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: can you please tell me, what is the use of 0 inside $cond?

Comment: if the `isBilling` is equal to `true` then we add `hours` to it else we add `0` to it.

Comment: Hi @Anthony, I need to use multiple groups in the same collection, how can i?

Comment: Better if you ask a new question :-)

Comment: I can ask if you want, but it is related to above question.

Comment: I would not have said for a new question if this is related to the above one. You should create a new one

Comment: okay, i will provide you link within 10 minutes after asking a new one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941136/aggregate-with-sum-in-mongodb

Comment: can you please make a look at this?