# Aggregate with $sum in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have data in `worksheets` collection like below:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c21d780f82aa31334ab6506"),
    "isBilling" : true,
    "hours" : 6,
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c1f38a1d7537d1444738467"),
    "projectId": ObjectId("5c1f38a1d7537d1444731234");
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c21d780f82aa31334ab6507"),
    "isBilling" : true,
    "hours" : 4,
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c1f38a1d7537d1444738493"),
    "projectId": ObjectId("5c1f38a1d7537d1444734567");
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c21e10fae07cc1204a5b647"),
    "isBilling" : false,
    "hours" : 8,
    "userId" : ObjectId("5c1f388fd7537d1444738492"),
    "projectId": ObjectId("5c1f38a1d7537d1444731234");
}
```

I am using below aggregate query to get total count of fields:

```
Worksheet.aggregate([
  {
    $match: conditions
  },
  {
   "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "billingHours": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$isBilling", true] }, "$hours", 0]
        }
      },
      "fixContract": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$isBilling", true] }, 0, "$hours"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Now i want the sum of unique `projectId` field. It above case it is **2**. I tried it by applying two $group in above implemented query. But it is not working. I want to get the result like below:

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "billingHours": 0,
    "fixContract": 8,
    "totalProjects": 2
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`$addToSet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) accumulator and then [**`$size`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator to count the number of unique `projectId`

```
Worksheet.aggregate([
  { $match: conditions },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "billingHours": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$isBilling", true] }, "$hours", 0]
      }
    },
    "fixContract": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$isBilling", true] }, 0, "$hours"]
      }
    },
    "projectIds": { "$addToSet": "$projectId" }
  }},
  { "$addFields": { "projectIds": { "$size": "$projectIds" }}}
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. But can you please explain what is $addToSet and $size here?

Comment: `$size` is used to count the number of elements inside an array. And `$addToSet` is used to add push elements(unique) inside an array,

Comment: You can ask here just as we are doing

Comment: No You cannot. Both are aggregation pipeline stages.

Comment: so, if i have to get the total count of projects from the projects collection, then how can i?

Comment: Use a `$lookup` stage after the `$group` stage. I have answered you so many times these type of `$lookup` queries. Please try understand them.

Comment: Yes you can ask a question

Comment: Are you checking?

Comment: Please ask a new question with proper explanation

Comment: I want to create api to get particular fields from multiple collections. How can i?